# Is there a way of finding the amount of people in a google meet and using it in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a program to automatically join my google meet at a certain time and leave when there are less than 5 people in the meeting. I am unable to find a way to see the number of people in a google meeting and put it into my code. Is there any way to achieve this?

Sorry if it formatted bad, it's my first proper post lol

[Here is a screenshot of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5gXJ.png) That I believe is correlated to the number of people in the meeting.

**Attached is the HTML text that I used in the code.**

```
<span jscontroller="FTBAv" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md;L6tSXb:B6c1Fe" class="wnPUne N0PJ8e">2</span>
```

**Below I attempted to find the class name but was unable to make this successfully work.**

```python
def peopleinclass():
    class_num = driver.find_element_by_class_name('wnPUne N0PJ8e')
    

    print(int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector
    ('div.eUyZxf span.rua5Nb').text.strip('(').strip(')')))
```

Comment: Without the relevant HTML, I'm not sure how we're going to be able to help you. Please edit your question and include it, properly formatted. Also, please fix the formatting of your code. It's hard to tell what's what with all the extra whitespace and some code not formatted as code.

Comment: Im sorry, its my first post on StackOverflow, I was unaware that we had a certain set to follow. I apologize.

Comment: Please post the HTML as text, properly formatted, instead of an image. That way we can test locators, etc.

Comment: is the one i put accurate?

Comment: I don't know if it's accurate, you would be the one to know that. I'm talking about the format. A screenshot of the page is fine, a screenshot of code or HTML is not very useful. Just copy the relevant HTML from the page and edit into your question as code so that it's formatted properly.

Comment: Yes, I just checked, it is accurate, but I am still unable to fetch the value changing when a new person joins the meeting